# Drag and drop jquery ui, dropping text into 2nd or + line in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two problems with my drag and drop of `li` to a `div`.

First - I am dropping the text into a div and it doesn't work very well, i need a better function to determine the characters in a line.

Second - whenever i drop an element over a already dropped element in the div it gets messed up, i need a function that if I drop on the other one it gives me the position on the end or beginning of that element.

Here the fiddle to help to see the problems. [Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1bk45v6/)

Here the jquery code:

```
var i = 0;

$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '#fullText',
  revert: "invalid",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "pointer"
});

$("#createButton").click(function(e) {
  $("#draggableList ul").append('<li  class="draggable" style="border:1px solid;padding:1px 5px" >' + $('#word').val() + '</li>');

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#fullText',
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "pointer"
  });
});


$('#fullText').droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {

    var height = $('#fullText').height();
    var line_height = $('#fullText').css('line-height');
    line_height = parseFloat(line_height);
    var lines = height / line_height;

    var height = $('#fullText').height();
    var lineHeight = $('#fullText').css('line-height');
    lineHeight = parseFloat(lineHeight);

    var dropPositionX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var dropPositionY = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    // Get mouse offset relative to dragged item:
    var dragItemOffsetX = event.offsetX;
    var dragItemOffsetY = event.offsetY;
    // Get position of dragged item relative to drop target:
    var dragItemPositionX = dropPositionX - dragItemOffsetX;
    var dragItemPositionY = dropPositionY - dragItemOffsetY;

    var lineNo = Math.round(dragItemPositionY / lineHeight);

    var charWidth = getCharWidth(this);

    var charactersinline = Math.round($('#fullText').width() / charWidth);


    //var chartPerrRow=Math.round(length/lineNo);

    // var el = document.getElementById("fullText"), 
    // lines = el.innerHTML.split("\n");


    var position = (Math.round(ui.offset.left / charWidth));
    position = position + (charactersinline * (lineNo));

    position = (position - 1 >= 0) ? position - 1 : position;
    i += 1;

    ui.draggable.remove();

    document.getElementById('fullText').innerHTML = $(this).html().substr(0, position + 1) + '<p style="padding:0; margin:0;display:inline;" id="' + i + '" contenteditable="false"  class="draggableP" > ' + ui.draggable.text() + '</p> ' + $(this).html().substr(position + 1);


    $(".draggableP").draggable({
      connectToSortable: '#fullText',
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    ui.draggable.remove();
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    // alert("out");
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {

  }

});


function getCharWidth(ele) {

  var f = window.getComputedStyle(ele)['font'],
    o = $('<div>' + ele.textContent + '</div>')
    .css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'float': 'left',
      'white-space': 'nowrap',
      'visibility': 'hidden',
      'font': f
    })
    .appendTo($('body')),
    w = o.width() / ele.textContent.length;
  o.remove();
  return w;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little unclear what you were trying to accomplish. This may work for you, yet it may nor be what you're looking for. Either way, it should help.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4mqvequ8/7/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $fT = $("#fullText");

  function makeDrag($item) {
    $item.draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "pointer",
      start: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Drag Start to: " + $fT.attr("id"));
        makeDrop($fT);
      }
    });
  }

  function makeDrop($item) {
    if ($item.hasClass("noEdit")) {
      console.log("No Edit found.");
      return false;
    }
    $item.addClass("noEdit").attr("contenteditable", false);
    console.log("Splitting words into elements.");
    var words = $item.text().split(" ");
    $item.html("");
    console.log(words);
    var i = 0;
    $.each(words, function(k, v) {
      var w = $("<span>", {
        class: "word word-" + k
      }).html(v + " ");
      w.appendTo($item);
      i++;
    });
    console.log("Created " + i + " word elements.");
    console.log("Making word elements droppable.");
    $item.find(".word").droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var newWord = ui.draggable.text();
        console.log("Drop Event for: " + newWord);
        $(this).after($("<span>", {
          class: "new word"
        }).html(newWord + " "));
        console.log("Returning word elements to text block.");
        makeText($fT);
      }
    });
  }

  function makeText($item) {
    console.log("Making Texct: " + $item.attr("id") + " From " + $item.find(".word").length + " words.");
    var words = $item.text().trim();
    $item.html(words).removeClass("noEdit").attr("contenteditable", true);
  }

  makeDrag($(".draggable"));

  $("#createButton").click(function(e) {
    var $li = $("<li>", {
      class: "draggable"
    }).html($('#word').val());
    $("#draggableList ul").append($li);
    makeDrag($li);
  });
});
```

Using a list of words, that can be dragged, the user can:

- Drag a word into the paragraph, that word will be appended after the word it was dropped upon
- Create new words to be added to the list

There is not a good way to append an element or text into a block of existing text. We can make an array of text items and add the new item into that array, yet this become exceptionally difficult to correlate the mouse drop position with a position in the string.

I figured it would be easier to convert each word into an HTML Element and then apply `.droppable()` to each element. Once a new word is dropped, return all the elements back into one text block.

This may break things like line breaks and the like.

Comment: thks, it is almost doind what i need, i only need to make the dropped text to be dragglable again after you drop it between the text.

Comment: @edounl This would not be able to do that. You could do this by retaining the `span` wrapping for `.new` or for all the words. It's not clear what your end goal is, so I do not know which would be best.

Comment: is there a way to count the characters, or words that are in a line  of  the div? i already have found out the number of lines and the line that it has been dropped.

Comment: @edounl it's not impossible, yet very tedious and difficult. Consider that text in a `div` will wrap based on it's width and and not the number of characters in a line or words in a line. You can attempt to calculate this based on a characters base width; yet this will be different for different for different font variables: size, style, family, letter spacing. Plus, a block of text has not elements, so there is very little for JS or jQuery to hook onto to manipulate the various portions of the text block. Please clarify your end goal.

Comment: This will be a text with gaps, for students to fill in the words in these places. 
So where i drop the words there will be empty places.
After the whole text is complete ill get the words and make empty places.
This is the teacher point of view, sort of back office to create the text. Maybe you know a better way to do this? thks for your help

Comment: @edounl this makes more sense now. It's a test / quiz. Students fill in answers, teachers use this to create the answers. You will need some type of wrapper. Something that can be used in HTML or in the text to identify the word versus the rest of the text.

Comment: i made something different, now i select the word, then i click on create button and it makes a span around the word , here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4tg43acL/